# Funtion to automate plotting. Various subplots and various figures

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot

I want to create a function that returns various figures with as many as 9 subplots inside each figure. That is, if I want 18 subplots I would like to have two figures with 9 subplots each.
And if I wanted to have 16 subplots, I want a have one figure with 9 subplots and another with only 7 subplots in a 3x3 grid.
First some toy data:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

rs = np.random.RandomState(444)
dates = pd.date_range(start="2009-01-01", end='2019-12-31', freq='1D')
values = rs.randn(4017,6).cumsum(axis=0)
data = pd.DataFrame(abs(values), dates, columns =['a','b','c','d','e','f'])
```

And now the code that I am using :

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(3,3, figsize=(15,6))
for (year, mini_df), ax in zip(data.groupby(data.index.year), axes.flatten()):
    mini_df['b'].plot(linewidth=1.5, ax=ax, ylim=(0,100))
    ax.set_title(year)
    ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.MonthLocator(bymonth=[1,3,6,9,12]))
    ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%b'))
```

which gets me this:[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Qk9a.png)

As you can see, there's still 2018 and 2019 that do not appear. I can add another row but I really would like to see how you people solve this. I cannot quite think my way to solve it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Apparently you always want full years. First, I'd compute the # of years from your dates. That gives you the # of plots. Then use integerdivision `//` and modulo `%` to get the number of  full 3x3 panels and the remainder for the last partial panel, respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Quite straight forward approach but it works.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

rs = np.random.RandomState(444)
dates = pd.date_range(start="2009-01-01", end='2019-12-31', freq='1D')
values = rs.randn(4017,6).cumsum(axis=0)
data = pd.DataFrame(abs(values), dates, columns =['a','b','c','d','e','f'])
df_group = data.groupby(data.index.year)
count = 0
col = 0
row = 0
fig, axes = plt.subplots(3,3, figsize=(15,6))

for year, index in df_group.groups.items():
    ax = axes[row, col]
    ax.set_title(year)
    ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.MonthLocator(bymonth=[1,3,6,9,12]))
    ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%b'))
    df_group.get_group(year).plot(linewidth=1.5, ax=ax, ylim=(0,100))        

    count += 1
    col += 1

    if count % 3 == 0:
        row += 1
        col = 0

    if count % 9 == 0:
        col = 0
        row = 0
        fig, axes = plt.subplots(3,3, figsize=(15,6))
```